# What are the consequences of homosexuality?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, sin, repentance-teshuvah, homosexuality

We all know that homosexual intercourse is forbidden in Judaism (directly from Torah).

But that it also has consequences in the spiritual world as everything in the physical realm has its correspondent in the spiritual world (also well written on gate of holiness):

"However, the spiritual
sustenance of the holy soul is drawn to it through the fulfillment of the Torah, which consists of 613
mitzvoth, corresponding to the 613 organs of the soul. Thus the Torah is called “bread”, as in the, “Come, partake of My bread”. Each of the 248 organs receives sustenance from a specific
mitzvah that relates to that organ. However, if a person lacks the fulfillment of any mitzvah, the
organ specific to that mitzvah will lack the sustenance drawn to it from the four letters of HaShem. "

See: 
https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380900/jewish/Male-Souls-and-Male-Sons-93.htm

I want to know, what are these consequences in the SPIRITUAL REALM?
i know many of the physical consequences.

I'm not talking about someone that did it with love or something like this. I'm talking purely about the sexual act and energy transmission.

semen has spiritual force and that males are more givers and females receivers. How can this semen from man to man affect both of them? How is this given to sitra achra?

How can this person recover from this sin?

Please answer with kabalistic sources.

Comment: I thought it was prohibited because God said so. I didn't know the reason was these consequences.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Hope to see you around!

Comment: My friend, WE KNOW THIS! For sure! But, imagine you made this sin but you started to see that this is affecting you in some spiritual realm. So you wanna repent from this. You have to be specific. If you stole, you have to payback the money, unfortunately some sins are very severe, understanding this helps lot of people in teshuvah.

Comment: Oh, right, i will put sourcers. I love this site, im always reading about halachic points and things like this here, but never posted here.

Comment: The internet is NO place for kabbalah.

Comment: I don't know about the kabbalistic consequences, but the purely physical ones are obvious...sore/damaged tuchases, fingernails(as well as bedposts and traffic cones, etc) that need extra scrubbing, nervous gerbils, etc.  Sorry, just couldn't resist a tongue-in-cheek(oops!)reply.  Yeah, I can see why HaShem would be against it.

Comment: @Gary Kabbalistic teachings say that everything in this material world has its root in the spiritual. That means that all these consequences you are mentioning have a corresponding spiritual source above. Consider that when you save a life, you save worlds. One of the consequences of committing homosexual acts mentioned in Talmud Yerushalmi is that it causes earthquakes in this world. That takes place via the spiritual intermediary.

Comment: @YaacovDeane - That sounds plausible.  I guess the Intermediary's not too happy with the state of things these days, and their Boss probably isn't too happy being referred to on a slogan on coins when their issuer permits wedding contracts to be drawn up(Didn't Sodom get it once that line was crossed?).  But there's an awful lot of room for teshuvah, for ALL of us, no doubt.  ..Just shows us how far from perfect we are, even without purposely trying to anger Him.

Comment: every sin creates a malach chabala

Comment: Thanks @YaacovDeane, i was talking about these kind of consequencies. I'm glad that you told me this, like you said, everything in this material world has its root in the spiritual, consequences in the spiritual source above.

Comment: @eeerrrttt 1. "imagine you made this sin but you started to see that this is affecting you in some spiritual realm" How can you be sure the affect on your spiritual realm was caused by homosexuality? Maybe it was because you gazed upon an immodestly "dressed" woman or spoke slander etc.? 2. "You have to be specific. If you stole, you have to payback the money..." Why don't you just assume: if you were acting homosexual, stop acting homosexual [and avoid things that may lead to such behavior]? Repentance shouldn't be done out of fear of the spiritual world - should be out of fear of God's word

Comment: Please check Tanya chapter 7 while it doesn't mention specifically homosexuality, it might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

> We all know that homosexual intercourse is not only forbidden in Judaism (directly from Torah) but that it also has consequences in the spiritual world.

Who is to decide what we all know? Last time I checked we refrained from doing sins because Gcd forbade them, and if we don't, then we'll suffer the consequences in the World-to-come.

I have no reason to believe *that it also has* any other *consequences in the spiritual world*.

> I'm not talking about someone that did it with love or something like this.

Why would it make a difference why a sin was done? And why would you do this type of sin if "love" was not involved?

> I'm talking purely about the sexual act and energy transmission.

Mixing art and science - and you call it pure? :-)

> We know that semen has spiritual force and that males are more givers and females receivers. How can this semen from man to man affect both of them?

Once again you decide what we all know. The effect is that they both have sinned and will suffer the consequences in the World-to-come.

> How is this given to sitra achra?

Syntax error. What are you trying to ask? Since when do we give anything to the *sitra achra* - a.k.a. *The Evil Inclination*?

> How can this person recover from this sin?

Like every other sin - with Teshuva: Stop doing the sin. Regret. Promising yourself never to do it again.

> Please answer with kabbalistic sources.

I believe this is not permitted in a public forum.

The Mishna in Chagiga 2:1 states that the hidden parts of the Torah are **not** to be taught at all, except to a single student at a time, a student who is wise enough to understand if you simply hint to him the subject matter.

Comment: +1. Although I thought Sitra achra was "the other side", i.e., evil as a force in the world rather than the evil inclination which pulls on man. Maybe there is no distinction but if there are two different sets of words, there might as well be two distinct concepts

Comment: Yes, i asked with this intention (the other side), not the "evil inclination".

Comment: @Danny, i have some considerations:

I said about 'love', because someone could argue the 'social', 'moral' kind of consequences.

Of course it's not a pure act, this is a sin, you can swap the word to 'just'

I asked about how can the act affect each one because it is written on gate of holiness about spiritual correspondence of the organs, and that each commandment is related to a spiritual sorce (Gate of holiness of Chaim vital).

Also according to gate of holiness, Chaim vital calls sitra achora by the other side (as my intention).

Comment: The question asked about Kabbalah. If you don't agree that we discuss it, then add a comment to the question, instead of making an answer. (Also, there's difference of opinions on regards to discussing Kabbalah.) זכר is the idea of נותן and נקבה is מקבל, which is the idea of מים דוכרין and מים נוקבין, and other kabbalistic ideas are based on this concept. If you don't want to answer the question, don't, instead of just bashing the question.